# How to pass parameters to function using rspec rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have following code like this in 'artists_helpers' class.

```
def round_to(x)
  (self * 10**x).round.to_f / 10**x
end
```

Similarly, in the artist_helper_spec.rb, I have code like this.

```
describe ArtistsHelper do
  it "should return a two digits after decimal" do   
    mock=12.234
    mock.round_to(2).should == 12.23
  end
end
```

How do I write script to make this function to test.

The problem is that, I dont get value of ':self' variable in helpers, when running rspec test.

Is their any other links which are helpful ?

Comment: I dont get value of ':self' variable in helper, when running rspec test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArtistHelper.round_to(2).should == 12.23